# Wear OS watch show FCM notification over wifi continually

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, wear-os

I'm trying to develop a firebase cloud messaging basic app on Wear OS. I am using android studio. and kotlin. watch is samsung gear watch 4
i have a few questions.

First of all, I want to keep the watch active so that the wifi stays on all the time. because I have to run the notifications independently from the phone.

like i solved this with wifiManager WifiLock. but I don't know if it's the right approach. I would be glad if you comment on this.

secondly, I am sending the notification via http post. When notifications start to accumulate on the Watch and exceed 25 messages, I get a warning in the log. The number of packet messages exceeded 25 messages. and new notifications stop displaying.

When a new notification arrives, I tried to delete previous notification messages and failed.
I've tried periodically deleting previous notification messages with jobScheduler without success.

Finally, I want the notification to be displayed regardless of whether the watch is worn on the wrist, whether the screen is off or not.

I'm not worried about battery usage.

I would like your opinion on these matters.

Thank you for your interest and I wish you good work.